# Javascript validation of html markup in a textarea object

Tags: javascript, validation

I'm surprised that I can't find anything on the net regarding javascript plugins to validate textarea objects for valid html markup. But the well is dry: does anyone know of a good example script that will parse the contents of a specified input and return false if it finds broken html markup within?

Comment: See this (note the use of `DOMParser`):
http://stackoverflow.com/a/15458968/3356679

Answer (score 7, accepted):

John Resig, the creator of jQuery, wrote an HTML parser:

http://ejohn.org/blog/pure-javascript-html-parser/

Comment: Do you need any more help with this question?