# Check if a text is HTML or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meteor

I am using Meteor and I am trying to check if a text is html. But usual ways do not work. This is my code:

```
post: function() {
    var postId = Session.get("postId");
    var post = Posts.findOne({
        _id: postId
    });
    var object = new Object();
    if (post) {
        object.title = post.title;
        if ($(post.content).has("p")) { //$(post.content).has("p") / post.content instanceof HTMLElement


            object.text = $(post.content).text();


            if (post.content.match(/<img src="(.*?)"/)) {
                object.image = post.content.match(/<img src="(.*?)"/)[1];
            }
        } else {
            console.log("it is not an html------------------------");
            object.text = post.content;
        }
    }
    return object;
}
```

Actually, this is the most "working" solution I have used up to now. Also, I pointed out the two most common ways which I use (next to the if statement). Is it possible to happen without regex.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what exact parts of HTML you would like to detect? Technically, this comment is valid HTML, but I assume you don't want to detect plain text.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458876/check-if-a-string-is-html-or-not it has a regex for detecting HTML elements. `/<[a-z][\s\S]*>/i.test()`

Comment: Actually in the html I want to detect there are <img> and <p> tags, so I use .text(), in order to obtain only the text, not out of the tags. But there are some occasions when the user input is only text, without tags.

Comment: Thank you Tennyson H, it works perfectly. Also I learned a lot from the the answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can use approach you already started with jQuery but append response to a new `<div>` and check if that element has children. If jQuery finds children it is html.

If it is html you can then search that div for any type of element using `find()`.

```
// create element and inject content into it
var $div=$('<div>').html(post.content);
// if there are any children it is html
if($div.children().length){
   console.log('this is html');
   var $img = $div.find('img');
   console.log('There are ' + $img.length +' image(s)');
}else{
   console.log('this is not html');
}
```

Comment: Thank you, actually this will help me to implement some other functionalities of my app.Together with the HTML validation.

Comment: is a bit more versatile than using a bunch of different regex

Comment: err! opening doors to XSS attacks

Answer (score 2):

Use the jquery [$.parseHTML](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) function to parse the string into an array of [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) nodes and check if it has any [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement).

```js
var htmlText = "----<b>abc</b>----<h3>GOOD</h3>----";
htmlText = prompt("Please enter something:", "----<b>abc</b>----");

var htmlArray = $.parseHTML(htmlText);

var isHtml = htmlArray.filter(function(e){ return e instanceof HTMLElement;}).length;

console.log(htmlText);
//console.log(htmlArray);

if (isHtml)
  console.log(isHtml + " HTML Element(s) found.");
else
  console.log("No HTML Elements found!");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```