# How to check and remove html tag from string

Tags: jquery, string

I'm trying to check first is mystring  contains any html tag.
If it contains Html tag then I want to remove those tag.

`var mystring = "<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit<p>&nbsp;amet, consectetur &nbsp;&nbsp;</p><p>adipiscing elit. Integer ut euismod magna, nec ullamcorper erat.</p></div>"`

from above string I need to remove all html tag and   also .
I'm new for these so. 
Please suggest something

Comment: What is your expected output from given input?

Comment: I need only text from these string

Comment: not a valid variable name (`my-string`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.text()` of **jQuery** like this:

```js
var myString = '<div class="ExpandedProfilePane-module_textField_delve fabric-module_ms-TextField_delve" contenteditable="true">Lorem ipsum dolor sit<p>&nbsp;amet, consectetur &nbsp;&nbsp;</p><p>adipiscing elit. Integer ut euismod magna, nec ullamcorper erat.</p></div>'

alert($(myString).text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also, using a variable name like `var my-string` is invalid so you also need to change that one

Comment: how can I caheck if string contains HTML

Comment: Check the approved answer in this another thread from StackOverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458876/check-if-a-string-is-html-or-not, it shows an example on how to use Regex to check if your string contains and HTML tag

Answer (score 2):

```
var my_string = '<div class="ExpandedProfilePane-module_textField_delve fabric-module_ms-TextField_delve" contenteditable="true">Lorem ipsum dolor sit<p>&nbsp;amet, consectetur &nbsp;&nbsp;</p><p>adipiscing elit. Integer ut euismod magna, nec ullamcorper erat.</p></div>'

$('#tst').html($(my_string).text());
```

**[Check Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/D2tEf/812/)**

Comment: how can I caheck if string contains HTML

Answer (score 0):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").remove(".test");
});
});
</script>

 </head>
  <body>


 <p class="test">This is another paragraph.</p>

 <button>Remove</button>

 </body>
 </html>
```